# MSBuild LibSass Error

Tags: msbuild, gulp-sass, libsass

Compiling Sass files using gulp-sass to css locally with no problem. On build machine, node modules are installed and when compiling .net code, getting error:

node_modules\node-sass\src\libsass\win\libsass.sln.metaproj:The specified solution configuration "debug|any cpu" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

I just want to be able to compile my sass into css. I'd rather not install Ruby on the build server.

Comment: If you've installed this through NPM, why are you calling the linsass solution build?

Comment: The complaint above is about using the "Any CPU" target on a C++ project that only has x86 and Win64 targets

Comment: did you figure this out? im having the same issue

Comment: I ran into this and I believe a big part in fixing it was making sure that you delete the node_modules folder after you run your gulp task and before the solution builds

Answer (score 4):

I've just had the same (or similar) issue.  In my case the build was being controlled by an Azure Devops pipeline and the *Build Solution* task was targeting "`**/*.sln`".  Changing this to "`SOLUTION_NAME.sln`" fixed the issue.

The reason the error happens is that after a `npm install` the `node_modules` folder contains some .sln files, which match the filter on the *Build Solution* task, so an attempt is made to build them.